# How to find the number checked rows of particular class type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below html table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Delete:<br><input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheckOne" class="deleteCheck" name="delete" value="0">
</td>
<td>
Delete:<br><input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheckTwo" class="deleteCheck" name="delete" value="0">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now using JQuery i have to find the `checked` count of the class `deleteCheck` using JQuery.

How can i fine the count of number of checked checked boxes using JQuery>

Thanks!

Comment: Both kayen and Rory answers are correct. Just to add a little bit, the ":checked" part is a selector that only works with jQuery. Take a look at [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to learn more about all the selectors jQuery offers you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the selector

```
$('input:checkbox:checked.deleteCheck').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.deleteCheck:checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:checked` selector to only find the `checked` inputs, and the `length` property to find out out many there are.

```
var checkedCount = $('.deleteCheck:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked rows can be selected by `:checked` and `length` gives you the count hence,this would help

```
$('.deleteCheck:checked').length;
```